# is it possible to load a transversal wave with a longitudinal wave

Tags: analog, communication, wave

like in communication engineering for sending information what we do,

we take a high frequency carrier and modulate it with the message signal

so can we do the same thing like take a high frequency carrier (transversal wave)

but the message is not transversal wave rather the message is longitudinal wave

say a sound wave

so can we modulate or load a transversal wave with a longitudinal wave ??

also if there is any work on this regard .. kindly post the link also??

Comment: Earthquakes produce both, but they travel at different speeds.  You can estimate the distance by the time of arrival between the sudden shock of the pressure wave then the side-to-side or up and down motion of the transverse.  Note that transverse waves will not travel through water.  So there's where you can start on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible and done in many applications, but probably not in the way you are thinking.  For all practical purposes EM waves are by definition transversal when in the far field plane wave mode and/or in free space which is illustrated below.  This is how a large majority of long distance communications operate.

[image: em wave]

This is not often the case in near-field applications or for Gaussian beam (laser) communications.  However this little fact doesn't mean you can also "load" them (we electron pushers prefer the term modulate) in a non-transverse way.  The E and H fields are all you have to work with so there's really nothing you can do.  Either you have TEM, TM or TE modes of propagation.

You can't really add information the way you are thinking...except, you can **accelerate the source**!  This will induce modulation in the form of a doppler shift.  You can then demodulate the doppler shift independently from the the data being transmitted.

But as far as I know that's about the only way you could do what I think you are asking in your question.  If I missed your point, then please clarify your question.

Comment: i know these things that for sending the info we need to send in TE, TM or TEM but what i want to do is send the acoustic waves(longitudinal) over large distance. acoustic waves gets very much damped because they tend to effect the medium of travel but it seems that after modulation we can send info on larger scale so i was thinking if we can modulate the longitudinal wave on  transverse then we can send the acoustic waves over large distance.

Comment: Not possible, so I gave you the only possible way of doing this via a modulation of a EM wave.